# Finding asymptote of $\sqrt[n]{p(x)}$

Tags: asymptotics, limits-without-lhopital

Suppose $p(x) = ax^n+bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2}+ \dots + z $ . Now find asymptote of $\sqrt[n]{p(x)}$ . I looked for it but I didn't find it and also couldn't solve it .

Example :
[image]

Comment: You need to say more.What if $a<0.?$ Then that $n$th root is not even defined for large $x.$

Comment: @zhw. Consider $\sqrt[n]{p(x)}$ is defined .

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as Argon's answer $$p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i=a_nx^n\left(1+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {a_i}{a_n x^{n-i}}\right)$$ Assume (wlog) $a_n >0$

$$\sqrt[n]{p(x)}=x\sqrt[n]{a_n}\left(1+ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac {a_i}{a_n x^{n-i}}\right)^{1/n}$$ Now, use the generalized binomial theorem (or Taylor series) to get 
$$\sqrt[n]{p(x)}=x\sqrt[n]{a_n}\left(1+\frac{a_{n-1}}{na_n x}+\cdots\right)=x\sqrt[n]{a_n}+\frac{a_{n-1}\sqrt[n]{a_n}}{n\,a_n}\cdots$$ which is the asymptote.

Comment: My teacher told me that asymptote is $\sqrt[n]{a}|x+\frac{b}{na}|$ line .

Comment: @S.H.W. I agree with that. What is $b$ ?

Comment: $p(x) = ax^n+bx^{n-1} + cx^{n-2}+ \dots + z$

Comment: @S.H.W. Replace the coefficients by numbers and ask Wolfram Alpha  something like $\text{asymptote of}$ $(9x^4+3x^3+7x^2+11x+124)^{1/4}$ $ \text{ when x to infinity}$

Comment: I've added it to my question .

Comment: @S.H.W. For me, what WA produces is $$\sqrt{3} x+\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{53}{96 \sqrt{3}
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yes , that is right . If you simplify that get $\sqrt{3}x + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}$ .

Comment: I think you made a mistake in the last line . It should be $\frac{\sqrt[n]{a_n}a_{n-1}}{na_n}$ .

Comment: @S.H.W. You are correct ! I shall edit.

Comment: Thank you but I'm not aware of generalized binomial theorem . Can you explain briefly ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it helps to notice that

$$\sqrt[n]{a_n x^n+\dots+a_0} = x\sqrt[n]{a_n+\frac{a_{n-1}}{x}\dots+\frac{a_{0}}{x^n}}$$

if $x > 0$.

Comment: It's undetermined still . We need more steps to solve it .

Comment: @S.H.W ...It's a hint. I don't think that should earn a downvote, at any rate.